# Outline any block of content on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently in a web cms we are building, we allow users to include any arbitrary content (be it plain text or any html content) to be displayed at any part of the web site. These blocks are called widgets (and obviously we take action to clean them up for security purpose).

I would like to be able to highlight these blocks for debugging purpose when necessary, however I cannot wrap them in any additional elements (such as div) as it may break the layout. I found several questions on this site regrading the same question yet have not any good solution yet.

It would be nice if we are allowed to use some kind of non-layout element (such as the comment tags) to wrap around block of contents to be able to do some action such as highlighting like this, but I have not found any way to do that.

I'm comfortable with any solutions (js, server based, etc) as long as it allows me to outline any block of content without breaking the layout. Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

A few example of widget contents:

**Text only widget:**

```
this is a the content of text only widget, there is also no wrapper here.
```

**HTML widget:**

```
<h1>Hello world </h1>

<section class="content">
    The problem here is that we do not want to force the users to 
    always wrap their contents inside a root element.
    In this example you can see that the content contains 1 h1 element
    and 1 section element. To outline this whole widget we may need to 
    wrap it by an outer element which may break the layout.
</section>
```

Comment: How do you identify them for the cleanup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly what you wanted, but it might be close enough ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gbxzh4uL/8/)). The script will wrap widgets with a `<span class="highlight">`. The span **should** not effect layout in any way:

```
.highlight {
    display: block; // this will change the layout as it inserts a line break
    outline: 1px dashed red;
}
```

When rendering the html, add a comment before and after a widget:

```
<!--!!!start widget!!!-->
this is a the content of text only widget, there is also no wrapper here.
<!--!!!end widget!!!-->
```

When you move to debug mode, run this script to add the highlight span:

```
var START_WIDGET = '!!!start widget!!!';
var END_WIDGET = '!!!end widget!!!';

function filter( node ) {
    if ( node.nodeValue !== START_WIDGET && node.nodeValue !== END_WIDGET) { // filter all comment nodes that are not start or end widget
        return( NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP );
    }
    return( NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT );
}

filter.acceptNode = filter;

var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT,
    filter,
    false
);

var start = null;

while ( treeWalker.nextNode() ) {
    if(treeWalker.currentNode.nodeValue === START_WIDGET) {
         start = treeWalker.currentNode;
    } else if(treeWalker.currentNode.nodeValue === END_WIDGET) {
        highlight(start, treeWalker.currentNode);
        start = null;
    }
}

function highlight(start, end) {
    var currentNode = start.nextSibling;
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    var temp;

    span.className = 'highlight';

    while(currentNode !== end) {
        temp = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.nextSibling;
        span.appendChild(temp);
    }

    $(span).insertAfter(start);
}
```

The [treeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) code is based on this article - [Finding HTML Comment Nodes In The DOM Using TreeWalker](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2607-finding-html-comment-nodes-in-the-dom-using-treewalker.htm)

Comment: I like the idea, yet there is no guaranty that the widget will be wrapped in any element (for example, the widget could be a text only widget), or the content could contain multiple elements with no root. I will add some examples on the question.

Comment: Each widget content should be input via a form, we strip out dangerous javascript tags and such before inserting into database. When we render the widgets we print them out from database content.

Comment: When in debug mode, can we wrap the elements, even though the layout might change a bit?

Comment: It's possible, but it's the last resort I want to try as I want to keep the layout intact if possible.

Comment: Almost perfect, I think I found an issue happens when we have rogue plain text mixed in http://fiddle.jshell.net/gbxzh4uL/6/ I will try to debug the js and find out why.

Comment: Updated the code again to catch all rogues, but the css needs `display: block` to highlight all, and that will change layout a bit - [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gbxzh4uL/8/).

Answer (score 1):

Try the style property, `outline`. It's like `border` but it's size doesn't affect layout. Wrap your widgets in `<span>`s as they are inline elements, which makes them perfect if you don't want to disrupt your layout. In addition to the use of `outline` and `<span>`, you can use the *defaults* to facilitate a smooth even layout.

**CSS**

```css
/* DEFAULTS */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.45'Source Code Pro';
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
}
/* WIDGETS */

.widget {
  outline: 3px dashed orange;
}
.widget.text {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
.widget.html {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.widget.html > .content {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="widget text">
this is a the content of text only widget, there is also no wrapper here.
</span>
<span class="widget html">
<h1>Hello world</h1>

<section class="content">
    The problem here is that we do not want to force the users to 
    always wrap their contents inside a root element.
    In this example you can see that the content contains 1 h1 element
    and 1 section element. To outline this whole widget we may need to 
    wrap it by an outer element which may break the layout.
</section>
  </span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Ori Dori added his answer first which is similar so I marked his as "answer". Best.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. :)